# Howto use Google DNS with ppp

Tags: linux, dns

I have a mobile broadband device that I use to connect to the internet. I wish to use the google dns service, their nameservers being `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.8.4`. 
I add them to `/etc/resolv.conf` but when I connect with wvdial,

```
➜  ~  sudo wvdial mts
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT#777
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT#777
CONNECT 3100000
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Sat Sep  1 19:45:18 2012
--> Pid of pppd: 3298
--> Using interface ppp0
--> local  IP address 180.215.45.164
--> remote IP address 10.228.138.133
--> primary   DNS address 10.228.129.114
--> secondary DNS address 10.228.129.113
```

This updates my `resolv.conf` to the new DNS servers. The problem is that my ISP's DNS service is buggy and I wish to use either google dns or opendns. How do I achieve this? 
I am running chakra linux (2012.08.22 - Claire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/0dns-up` which will setup DNS records, so remove execution bit and use google dns statically.

`chmod -x /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/0dns-up`

And modify /etc/resolv.conf to use google dns only (you've done that already)

Comment: Is their some way that I can verify that my dns has been changed using some website or tool?

Comment: @nikhil you don't need to, since all programs use glibc function to resolve an address unless it parses DNS packets itself..but if you insist, check output with `dig www.google.com`

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I have learned something new today.